# Scrapy only returning 400 http code errors

Tags: python, nginx, scrapy, http-status-code-400

I am running scrapy on many different websites. No matter what site I choose, scrapy returns one 200 code, and the rest 400, making my crawler useless. Any idea why?

```
{'downloader/request_bytes': 14495,
{'downloader/request_bytes': 14495,
 'downloader/request_count': 25,
 'downloader/request_count': 25,
 'downloader/request_method_count/1': 24,
 'downloader/request_method_count/1': 24,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 11208,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 11208,
 'downloader/response_count': 25,
 'downloader/response_count': 25,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/400': 24,
 'downloader/response_status_count/400': 24,
```

The downloader/response_status_count/400 is always 99.99% of the response. I've tried this on over 100 different sites, always the same issue.

Please note, I am using proxies. Also, on multiple (separate) sites now, I have gotten this error:

```
<html>\r\n<head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>\r\n<body bgcolor="white">\r\n<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>\r\n<hr><center>nginx</center>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>
```

Why would I be getting an nginx error?

Comment: The '400 Bad Request'  is an  HTTP response status code that indicates that the server was unable to process the request sent by the client due to invalid syntax.

Comment: Any idea why? If my syntax was invalid, shouldn't it fail for every request? Is there anyway to see the "Curl" equivalent of the twisted request using scrapy?

Comment: Can you post the part of your code where you are yielding the failed request? This error occurs when you have an invalid request, passing wrong headers or so.